# How can I declare a variable as an argument and print a desired subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the value of a specific subdirectory like `subDir[2]`, from a root directory. I want to make an argument `subDir` in `listdirs()` function i.e. `listdirs(rootdir, subDir[2], count)` this should directly return me the value of `subDir[2]`.

Instead of printing `subDir[2]` outside the loop, how can I print the desired subdirectory by just calling a function? How can I use `subDir` as an argument in `listdirs` function with `rootdir` and `count` also?

```
import os

subDir = []
def listdirs(rootdir, count):
    def recurse(rootdir):
        nonlocal count
        for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
            d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
            if os.path.isdir(d):
                recurse(d)
                count += 1
                subDir.append(d)
    recurse(rootdir)
    print(f"Total directories are {count}")

rootdir = ('/home/runner/TestP1')
count = 0
listdirs(rootdir, count)
print(subDir[2])
```

Comment: Try returning `subDir` variable @floated variable

Comment: @Vishnudev I didn't understand

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide an example of what you expect the output to be. It sounds like you just want to `return` from the function.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of printing subDir[2] outside the loop, how can I print the desired subdirectory by just calling a function?

If you want to print `subDir[2]` from running the function, you could do something like this:

```py
import os

rootdir = ('test')
count = 0
subDir = []

def listdirs(rootdir, count, target_count):
    result = []
    def recurse(rootdir):
        nonlocal count
        nonlocal target_count
        for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
            d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
            if os.path.isdir(d):
                recurse(d)
                if count == target_count:
                    print(f'Found {d} - directory number {target_count}')
                count += 1
                subDir.append(d)
    recurse(rootdir)
    print(f"Total directories are {count}")

listdirs(rootdir, count, 2)
print(subDir[2])
```

Using my sample folder `test`, I get this output:

```
Found test/second/third - directory number 2
Total directories are 4
test/second/third
```

> I want to get the value of a specific subdirectory like subDir[2], from a root directory. I want to make an argument subDir in listdirs() function i.e. listdirs(rootdir, subDir[2], count) this should directly return me the value of subDir[2].

Do you mean a listing of subDir[2], or just its path? Or do you mean the second subdirectory in rootdir? You could replace the `print(f'Found {d} - directory number {target_count}')` with a suitable `return` or variable assignment, which would give you the subdirectory path.

> How can I use subDir as an argument in listdirs function with rootdir and count also?

That depends on what it is you want to do with it, can you give any more detail?

Additionally there is a standard library function [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), for traversing directories, which you may find useful as well.